# Laravel query builder. Column if not null = 1 else = 0 in select method

Tags: sql, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I using Laravel and its `\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder`. I would like to select all columns from "table_1" a have custom column "is_table_2_present" which value will be 1 or 0 depending if(table_1_id != null).

So I would like to do something like that.

```
$queryBuilder->leftJoin("table_2"....)

$queryBuilder->select([
    "table_1.*",
    "is_table_2_present" = (table_2_id != null) ? 1 : 0,
]);
```

I was trying to search for an answer but without much of a success. So I would like to ask if something like that is possible?

The reason why I cannot use Eloquent relationship is because I would need relationship with parameter. And that not possible in laravel 5.2 right?

```
public function table_2($userId)
{
    return $this->hasOne(Table_2::class....)->where(user_id, "=", userId);
}
```

Comment: You may have a legitimate reason to do this raw query but is there a reason you aren't using Eloquent relationships?

Comment: I working with a legacy code and kinda need to do it this way. So your recomendation would be simply to use `->selectRaw()`?

Comment: @Spholt  I edited the question to explain why I can not use Eloquent relationships

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this question kinda died, no respons for a while I solved it with selectRaw() for now. But still in search for more neat solution.

```
$queryBuilder->selectRaw("
    table_one.*,
    CASE WHEN table_two.id IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS tableTwoPresent
");
```

Answer (score 1):

Conceptually each table is associated to a model. Try eloquent relationship between the models of the two table you are trying to query.

Comment: I'm working with a legacy code and kinda need to do it this way withou Eloquent relationship in this case

Comment: Or is it possible to create a relationship with parameter laravel 5.2?

Answer (score 1):

You can use selectRaw(), I think it will be:

```
$queryBuilder->selectRaw(
             <<<EOT
               table_1.*,
               if(table_2_id != ?, 1, 0) as is_table_2_present, 
             EOT,
             [null]
             );
```

In the above code, I used binding to avoid the SQL injection.